# How to Get Data size of SQL MI from a Subscription using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I want to get Data sizes of SQL MI Storage Accounts from multiple Subscriptions. For instance, we have a Subscription which has SQL MI configured to it in WestUS2 Region.

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | ft

ResourceGroupName Location ProvisioningState Tags TagsTable ResourceId                                                                          ManagedBy
----------------- -------- ----------------- ---- --------- ----------                                                                          ---------
HyperNet_RG       westus2  Succeeded         {}             /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/HyperNet_RG               
NetworkWatcherRG  westus2  Succeeded                        /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG          
SQL_MI_RG         westus2  Succeeded         {}             /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/SQL_MI_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get Data sizes of SQL MI Storage Accounts from multiple Subscriptions.

You only can get all the information of SQL managed instances in one resource group from current Subscription with PowerShell.

**Example : Get all instances assigned to a resource group**

```
Get-AzSqlInstance -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
Location                 : westcentralus
Id                       : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resourcegroup01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/managedInstance1
ResourceGroupName        : resourcegroup01
ManagedInstanceName      : managedInstance1
Tags                     :
Identity                 : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ResourceIdentity
Sku                      : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.Models.Sku
FullyQualifiedDomainName : managedInstance1.wcusxxxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net
AdministratorLogin       : adminLogin1
AdministratorPassword    :
SubnetId                 : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resourcegroup01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet_name/subnets/subnet_name
LicenseType              : BasePrice
VCores                   : 8
StorageSizeInGB          : 512

Location                 : westcentralus
Id                       : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resourcegroup01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/managedInstance2
ResourceGroupName        : resourcegroup01
ManagedInstanceName      : managedInstance2
Tags                     :
Identity                 : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ResourceIdentity
Sku                      : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.Models.Sku
FullyQualifiedDomainName : managedInstance2.wcusxxxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net
AdministratorLogin       : adminLogin2
AdministratorPassword    :
SubnetId                 : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resourcegroup01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet_name/subnets/subnet_name
LicenseType              : BasePrice
VCores                   : 8
StorageSizeInGB          : 512
DnsZone                  : ad35cna0mw
```

For more details, please reference [Get-AzSqlInstance: Returns information about Azure SQL Managed Database Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlinstance?view=azps-2.7.0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using the same commandlet (Get-AzSqlInstance). I'm only getting reserved space on the SQL Resource Group. Hopefully Microsoft Azure team exposes a commandlet to displace the space by SQL instance in Azure soon.

Comment: @Vinny yes, we also hope so. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer?  This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much and have a good day!

Comment: I'm trying to find the option "Accept as Answer" But unable to find it here on this page. :(

Comment: Hi @Vinny, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!